# Can i serve media files on production server in Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-media

Actually I created a fully functional web app using Django. I don't have much experience to host a Django web app on a production server. But I'm trying. My problem is that I read from a blog that we can't serve media files using Django. We need Amazon S3 server to serve media files to Django. I'm trying to host my Django app on digital ocean with apache server. Is there any way that I can serve media files using Django in production server. Even I don't have a huge budget to buy a space on Amazon S3. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the open-source self-hosted S3 implementation - [Minio](https://min.io).

Another approach is to serve static files using web-server.
There is [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) with nginx.